# Decomposition of bordism groups for $BG$ where $G$ is a product of two groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cobordism

Let a group $G=G_1 \times G_2$, where

- $G_1$ is a discrete group (can be finite or infinite),
- $G_2$ be any compact Lie group or finite group.

> Question: Is there some simple result that we can decompose the spin and pin bordism groups
>   $$\Omega^{Spin}_d(BG),$$
>   $$\Omega^{Pin^{+/-}}_d(BG),$$
>   into lower dimensions of
>   $\Omega^{Spin}_n(BG_1)$ and $\Omega^{Spin}_m(BG_2)$ and their sums or compositions.

For example, I can prove that
$$\Omega^{Spin}_d(B(\mathbb{Z} \times G_2))=
\Omega^{Spin}_d(B(G_2)) \times \Omega^{Spin}_{d-1}(B( G_2)),$$
when $G_2$ is any group.

How about the decomposition of

> $$\Omega^{Spin}_d(B(G_1 \times G_2)),$$
>   $$\Omega^{Pin^{+/-}}_d(B(G_1 \times G_2)),$$
>   for the criteria of $G=G_1 \times G_2$ given above?
>   Similar to Künneth formulas/theorem for bordism groups.

[Related questions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/313521/27004) [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/313521/27004).

Comment: Of course $B(G_1\times G_2)\cong BG_1\times BG_2$. I never read about this, but there are Künneth formulas for bordism groups, I believe due to Landweber here :https://www.jstor.org/stable/1994343?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents . So you might use this to compute things